# Angular Component Library project with NGRX store

Tags: angular, angular7, ngrx

I have searched around and cannot find any examples of the following.

What I am after is the ability to create a reusable angular component library with its own store, reducers, service etc. The initialState of this store will be injected by the main application.

In the end, this package will be installed into each feature module using a different initialstate;

```
imports: [
  ...,
 storeLib.use({ initialState: INITAL_MODEL })
]
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: This question seems too broad for stackoverflow. What is your exact question?